# How to display yarn globally installed packages?

Tags: yarnpkg

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.4 and I have installed yarn by `brew install yarn` and its version is `yarn version v0.23.2`

I installed `angular-cli`, `bower` and `ionic` using `yarn global add <package-name>`

**Then I use `yarn global ls` to display globally installed packages and I am expecting to see the above installed packages but yarn gives me this:**

```
$ yarn global ls                                                               
yarn global v0.23.2
warning No license field
✨  Done in 0.99s.
```

Then i check `yarn global bin` and get path `/Users/myusername/.config/yarn/bin` and I go to the directory and see softlinks:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  staff    38B 19 Apr 10:17 bower -> ../global/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  staff    42B 19 Apr 10:21 cordova -> ../global/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  staff    38B 19 Apr 10:20 ionic -> ../global/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  staff    41B 19 Apr 10:15 ng -> ../global/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng
```

Apparently all packages were installed and saved under `/Users/myusername/.config/yarn/global/node_modules`

I searched the following threads
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2446

Tried appending the below paths but still not work:

```
YARN_BIN=$HOME/.config/yarn/bin  # `yarn global bin` result
export PATH=$YARN_BIN:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
```

Can anyone help? What should I do and how to display the globally installed packages?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`yarn global list`

The command had [issue in Spring 2017](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2354), that had been fixed.

### 2017 workaround

Currently I directly list [Yarn global packages folder](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2049#issuecomment-263183768) content:

- Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/config/global`
- OSX and Linux non-root: `~/.config/yarn/global`
- Linux if logged in as root: `/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global`

### Update June 22, 2020

As of May 12, 2017 this problem has been resolved. [See issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2354) and [pull request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/3308).

So you can use `yarn global list` to list all globally installed packages.

Comment: @toomuchdesign thanks for your reply, I knew `yarn global list` was abandoned.. seems like checking `~/.config/yarn/global` is the only way to list globally installed packages..thanks again.

Comment: Just used global list now and it seems not broken anymore.

Comment: Just used Global list now and it seems to only return the Yarn version number, and the Windows directory is now `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/Data/global`

Answer (score 15):

`yarn global list` has been fixed, see [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2354) and [pull request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2354).

Comment: This answer should have been accepted since Sep 2017

Answer (score 3):

I have did some research for a couple of days but haven't get quite helpful solutions. 
[#2224](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2224) [#3142](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3142) and some other Github issues relate to this.

This is how I get the global installed packages so far:

1. go to `~/.config/yarn/bin`, it shows the packages but no version tags.
2. go to `~/.config/yarn/global` and run `cat package.json` to display the installed packages

Content:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "yo": "^1.8.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "cordova": "^6.5.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "^4.3.0",
    "ionic": "^2.2.2",
    "ts": "^0.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
    }
}
```

To check whether the info is accurate, I run `yarn global remove yo`, then `yo` is gone in the `~/.config/yarn/bin` folder and then I `cat package.json` again and yo has removed from the file as well.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "cordova": "^6.5.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "^4.3.0",
    "ionic": "^2.2.2",
    "ts": "^0.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

`npm` works perfectly on my machine but yarn is much faster, that's why I don't want to go back to npm...
Hope someone can provide more elegant way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution here in windows 10:

`C:\Users\{YOUR_USERNAME}\node_modules\.bin`

just add this path to my `environment variables`

Comment: In Linux, it can be generally found in: ` ~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin`. Just in case anyone needs!