# Is there any difference between installing global packages with Yarn or NPM?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Does it matter whether you install a global package with `yarn global add PACKAGE` vs `npm install -g PACKAGE` ?

Is there any difference at all, like where files are installed?
If yes, what is it?

Comment: Is this a generic question or you have a specific problem which is happening with a difference between the two?

Comment: I suspect I have troubles with some global packages behaving differently with installing with yarn vs npm. But I can't say for sure. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Could you please clarify the name of few packages for which you are facing issues?

Answer (score 6):

So yes, you are right it is different. For `npm` it is something like below

`/Users/tarunlalwani/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib` if you are using nvm

You can get this path using

```
$ npm config get prefix
/Users/tarunlalwani/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0
```

[Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

While yarn uses other paths

- Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/config/global
- OSX and Linux non-root: ~/.config/yarn/global
- Linux if logged in as root: /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global

[How to display yarn globally installed packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501514/how-to-display-yarn-globally-installed-packages)

See this thread as well

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2049

Comment: So does this path difference mean with Yarn the global packages are not associated with your NVM version of Node? Meaning you should use `npm` instead of `yarn` for global packages if you use NVM?

Comment: @AlecRust `nvm` installs yarn underneath its version controlled directory. So if you print out `which yarn` it would be installed in a directory like `/Users/{username}/.nvm/versions/node/{version}/bin/yarn`. Hence no problem with global installations on either `npm` or `yarn` even when using `nvm`

Answer (score -1):

This is the document about [Yarn global](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global)

> yarn global is a prefix used for a number of commands like add, bin,
>   list and remove. They behave identically to their normal versions
>   except that they use a global directory to store packages. The global
>   command makes executables available to use on your operating system

and this is the document about [npm install global mode](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html)

> In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it
>   installs the current package context (ie, the current working
>   directory) as a global package.

I think there is no difference between them. Install a package as a global useful for developer tooling that is not part of any individual project but instead is used for local commands