# Is there a command to unlink all yarn packages? yarn unlink all

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'd like to see a list of all yarn linked packages everywhere on my computer and then run a command to unlink all of them. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Don't know if this is the yarn way to do things, but I just :

`rm -rf ~/.config/yarn/link/*`

Comment: And for Windows remove all files from C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link

Answer (score 8):

You can create aliases

```
alias yarn-linked="find . -type l | grep -v .bin | sed 's/^\.\/node_modules\///'"
alias yarn-unlink-all="yarn-linked | xargs yarn unlink && yarn install --check-files"
```

Credit [hubgit](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1722#issuecomment-512937082)

Comment: This is closer to what I want but when I try running yarn-unlink-all I get a bunch of warnings: 

find: ./Library/Containers/com.apple.VoiceMemos: Operation not permitted
.. etc ...
find: ./Library/Containers/com.apple.archiveutility: Operation not permitted
xargs: yarn: Argument list too long

Comment: i don't have this problem... hm did you update ` ~/.bash_profile` exactly with the code? if you just copy and paste these 2 lines into terminal, and run yarn-unlink-all, you get the errors?

Comment: actually this is not to unlink from your whole computer, just local CWD packages

Comment: Added yarn-linked to package.json and got `error An unexpected error occurred: "/home/vitaly/myproject/package.json: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 833".`

Answer (score 4):

There is an [Issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8084) for this feature.

The only surefire way I know of is to nuke node_modules:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && yarn
```

I know, I know, horrible solution. If someone knows a better way, please inform.

Answer (score 3):

Links are registered in `~/.config/yarn/link`. To reverse this process or unlink, simply use:

```
yarn unlink
```

or

```
yarn unlink [package]
```

**EDIT:**

You can try by add following in bash.rc:

```
alias yarn-linked="find . -type l | grep -v .bin | sed 's/^\.\/node_modules\///'" 
alias yarn-unlink-all="yarn-linked | xargs yarn unlink && yarn install --check-files"
```

Comment: Is there a way to unlink all of them at the same time through a single command?

Comment: This i found online check my answer for credit you need 2 lines in bash.rc `alias yarn-linked="find . -type l | grep -v .bin | sed 's/^\.\/node_modules\///'"`
`alias yarn-unlink-all="yarn-linked | xargs yarn unlink && yarn install --check-files"`

Comment: `yarn unlink` is not an "unlink all" command. It only works in each individual package directory from which you ran `yarn link`

Comment: Thanks @zavr Running the command `yarn install --check-files` show the message :  warning The target of linked package "my-package" is missing. Removing link.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, they are stored in ~/.config/yarn/global

and you can remove with command yarn unlink [package]

Hope this will Help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747805/12318562

Comment: Is there a way to unlink all of them at the same time through a single command?

Comment: npm uninstall `ls -1 node_modules | tr '/\n' ' '` this will remove all packges with npm but yarn doesn't provider command to remove all packges with single command.